# C# Complex Property Setter option

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 (C#) application and I'm giving my users the ability to like posts and comments.

for this I have a Model called Likes with the following Properties:

```
public class Like
{
    public Like()
    {
        this.CreatedUTC = System.DateTime.UtcNow;
        this.isActive = true;
    }
    public long id { get; set; }
    public string UserID { get; set; }
    public bool isActive { get; set; }
    public LikeType Type { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedUTC { get; set; }  
}
```

`Type` is an enum and it can be either `Comments` or `Posts`. I've also added the following Navigation Property to both Post Model and Comment Model:

```
public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes { get; set; }
```

My question is, can I have a setter function in the above line of code where it would automatically set `Comments` and `Posts` for the Like type? I know I can use the `Value` variable in the Setter but using Google I couldn't find how to use it for complex types as I have above (`Like`).

I'm sure this would be a better way of doing this than in the repository manually set that enum every-time I'm going to save a like.

**UPDATE:**

Seeing how we're starting a nice little conversation about this Questions, I will throw another alternative in the mix.

How about two Tables with a base class of Like, one `CommentLikes` and the other `PostLikes` Seeing that the size of this table will grow really fast, I'm thinking separating them would possibly be a good thing, Right?

Comment: What are the `id`s? I'm wondering whether you can deduce the `LikeType` from there, perhaps using a look-up.

Comment: Entity Framework will implicitly add the ids, and you can actually deduce the type by that, I was just trying to put it in an enum.

Comment: +1 for appending UTC to the name of that DateTime property.

Comment: @Craig I just started doing that in this project. I was so tired of keeping track of all the utc values (although most if not all of my DateTimeProperties are UTC. I like it too!!

Comment: I came to the conclusion a long time ago that dates/times should probably always be stored as UTC nowadays and displayed using regional settings, and I really like that the property name disambiguates the issue for any consumers of your model. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd rather drop the "LikeType" and either have Comment and Post entity in the Like entity and distinguish by one of them being null or introduce two new entities

```
public class CommentLike
{
    public Comment Comment { get; set; }
    public Like Like { get; set; }
}
```

which holds a comment and a like and PostLike which holds a Post and a Like. The Comment then looks like this

```
public Comment
{
    public virtual ICollection<CommentLike> { get; set; }
}
```

Another alternative is to create separate tables for comment and post likes. While what you ask for is definitely doable I would recommend more verbose but simpler solution which will result in code that is easier to maintain and has less bugs. Is there any specific reason you want to have a LikeType property?

Comment: I honestly, just thought that it would come in handy one day. I'm in very early stages of development and am just creating the models right now. Which method would you recommend? Having one Like Table or separate one for each type?

Comment: The one with the special link type will probably result in the most correct database schema. I am all for correct database schema over easier code but this is just my point of view. Completely unrelated tables is definitely the simplest approach.

Comment: you mean LikeType right? Something is drawing me to that solution too but I can't help but to think having two different tables would make this easier (base class of `Like` and only one more property LikeType) and as you mentioned correct

Comment: I have updated my answer to further explain my idea. Your idea with inheritance is not bad either.

Answer (score 0):

> My question is, can I have a setter function in the above line of code
>   where it would automatically set Comments and Posts for the Like type?

I assume you are using T4 template or the classes that were generated by EF are `partial`then you can extend it by creating another partial class and a `wrapper property` for `Likes`

```
// Backing field
private ICollection<Like> _likesWrapper;
public ICollection<Like> LikesWrapper { 
get { 
  // Lazy loading
 if(_likes == null)
 { 
   // Just create a new list or load it from the database.
   _likes = new List<Like>(); 
 }
 return _likes; 
 }
set { 
 foreach(var val in value)
 {
   //Set the comment and posts
 }
 Likes = value;
}
```

Comment: @DarthVader Saying an answer is wrong without an explanation is useless.

Comment: No I m saying, that return _likes will return null, regardless. Then this is not the answer to question.

Comment: @DarthVader You know there's a null check and a comment do something. Oh wait, let me be explicit. Just for you.

Comment: what if 2 threads enter that Critical Section at the same time?

Comment: @DarthVader Sure, and we can do Mutex/Semaphore in it. We should keep it simple right now. Shouldn't we? Just answer the question don't make it too complex.

Comment: How can you know OP wont copy and paste that? + what does your foreach do there? it is not clear? how do you know the type of object if it is Post or Comment in your foreach?

Comment: Wouldn't this break because of the ORM? ORM's override setters and getters to implement lazy loading.

Comment: @DarthVader It's not my choice if he copy paste it. You want spoon feeding? Go ahead, please give him a step by step solution that he can copy paste. Easy, check the type in the foreach?

Comment: and what about lazy loading ? will u traverse all the likes in the application?

Comment: Turns out this is not so easy huh? is it?

Comment: @DarthVader I didn't say it was complex or easy.

Comment: @DarthVader Yeah, I was expecting something very simple lol. Thanks for the help guys

Comment: @hjavaher That is why i m saying. If you dont have a use case, if you wont need it. dont do it. In my case, i never needed such relationship.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem but didnt encounter an easy way.

```
class Post{
   public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes {set;get;}

}

class Comment{
   public virtual ICollection<Like> Likes {set;get;}

}

Then:

class Like{
  //....
}
```

You dont need a bi-directional relationship. Do you have a case where you need to query `Likes` table? and if you do, you will have to manage parsing it as ENUM somewhere which can be an extension method.

EF will create Post_Id and Comment_Id implicityly in your table design. You wont be able to query it but you wont need to. IN my experience i never needed to.

Comment: Did this not an answer the question. This looked to me you ended up asking question. Answering a question where you are not even completely sure what you just answered. Also, he is asking about the setter function.

Comment: Thanks for the help I'm considering separating the Tables now that I see all the comments